# PostgreSQL View - Getting earliest date from seperate column data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a view in PostgreSQL that utilizes both the `date_start` and `age` functions, to check the amount of day(s) remaining until a date.

The added complexity of getting such data, is the requirement to filter an 'latest' date from a column of multiple dates in another table, which is joined to the view.

I have tried to create a sub-select query within my view to try to get the Top 1 date from the external table, but I receive a syntax error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW calendar_date
AS 
SELECT product.deposit_id,
       date_part('day'::text, age(calendar."date"::timestamp with time zone, CURRENT_DATE::timestamp with time 4 zone)) AS product_start_days,
       date_part('day'::text, age(deposit.payable_datetime::timestamp with time zone, CURRENT_DATE::timestamp 6 with time zone)) AS payable_days
FROM db.product product
LEFT JOIN db.deposit deposit on deposit.id = p.deposit_id
LEFT JOIN db.calendar calendar on calendar.id = product.calendar_id;
```

On line 3, the view returns ALL the counts until ALL dates in `db.calendar` instead of just the 'latest' date.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that `date_part('day', ...)` does **not** return the length of the interval in days. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=420125e04be7b16021408e13e687aba9 If you use `calendar."date"::date - current_date` you'll get the difference in days

Comment: Earliest date for what? Some example data would go a long way to make this clearer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name doesn't the `age` function perform the interval?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver there are 100's of entries in the database table `calendar`, in which a column called `date` holds values of the data type `timestamp without timezone`. E.g. 2020-11-30, 2020-11-21, 2020-12-01...

Comment: @LJones: yes, the age() function returns an interval. But that could be `3 years  2 months 14 days` - and `date_part('day', ...)` would then only return `14`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Okay, say if I use this, how would I apply such function to `calendar."date"`, I need to extract the 'earliest' date from that column, earliest being the date closest to the current_date.

Comment: You have just reversed the meaning of earliest. Earliest is the date furthest back in time. So are you looking for that or the latest date that is not the current date?

Comment: Then edit your question to reflect that and also provide a small example data set showing what you want to happen.